# refresh previous page in framework 7 when click on back navigation button(pages are ajax-pages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-framework-7

Almost spend a day but couldn't make it work to refresh the previous sub category page once the item form is filled and when press back button on the framework 7 navigation.

so my pages are 
-category
-sub-category
-item(form) (when click on navigation back button then needs to go to sub-category page. Where the sub-categories get refresh so that I know this subcategory form is filled )

However, it's not working my pages developed using ajax-page functionality. So please let me know what I should use to make it work and refresh the previous page.

Well, I have used following code on my category page and when I click on any category then it refresh the sub category page but not refresh sub-category page after coming from form.:(

ajax-page means my all the pages begin with following line:

```
<div data-page="form_category" class="page">
```

mycode of category page which refresh the subcategory page is here:

```
<a href="form_subcategory.php?cat=<?php echo $category['id'];?>" class="item-link"  **data-reload="false" data-force="true" data-ignore-cache="true"**>
```

my code of item page which is not refreshing the subcategory page when click back:

```
 <div class="left sliding"><a data-reload="false" data-reload-previous='true' data-force="false" data-ignore-cache="true" href="form_subcategory.php?subcat=<?php echo $subcategory_info['id'];?>" class="back link"  ><i class="icon icon-back"></i></a></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am still waiting for someone to help me here with the issue here.

Comment: DO you have test with `data-reload="true"` ?

Comment: which version of F7?